# Самовызываемые стрелочные функции

Tags: javascript

Подскажите в чем отличия и почему вариант со стрелочными функциями не работает?

```js
var obj = {
  a: 10,
  b: (function() {
    return this.a
  })()
}
console.log(obj);

var obj = {
  a: 10,
  b: (() => {
    this.a
  })()
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Они оба "не работают".

Comment: var obj = {
  a: 10,
  b: (function () {
    return 20;
  }())
}

Comment: подобный код можно ли на стрелочные переписать?Главным условием становится то, что функция должна быть самовызываемая

Comment: Можно, только в вашем коде весь вопрос в том, что такое `this`. Попробуйте вывести его значение

Comment: This действительно написан некорректно, однако, как в таком случае вывести, например, статичное число?

Comment: `get b(){return (() => this.a)();}` или `get b(){return (function(){return this.a}).call(this);}`. На момент вычисления выражений для присваивания свойствам в литерале объекта не существует самого объекта и нет никакой возможности ссылаться на его отдельные свойства. Но прописав геттер, на момент обращения к нему доступ получить можно.

Answer (score 0):

> var obj = { a: 10, b: (function () { return 20; }()) }
>
> подобный код можно ли на стрелочные переписать?Главным условием
> становится то, что функция должна быть самовызываемая

```js
//var obj = { a: 10, b: (function () { return 20; }()) } 
var obj = { a: 10, b: (() => 20)() };
console.log(obj);
```